# How to create custom metadata tag for CQ

Tags: metadata, aem

I am trying to create a custom metadata tag for all JPEG images. Following the documentation this is what I did in `/apps`

[image]

However, when I upload a new JPEG file I don't see the tag I've added (`Atest`)

Am I missing something? I copied `/libs/dam/content` to `/apps/dam/content` and just kept the `assetededitors` folder and I modified the `formitems` under the `image/jpeg` folder as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Did you remember to save changes in CRX DE?

Comment: Yeah, I saved everything in CRX DE Lite. Now, when I import a new JPEG image I don't see the `Atest` tag. This is all I see: http://cl.ly/WGbD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asseteditors` node allows you to change the classic DAM metadata editor, available under the `/damadmin`. The screenshot attached in the comment presents new touch UI which can be enhanced using Javascript as [in this article](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2014/05/aem-cq-561-add-new-image-metadata-field-in-touchui.html).